# Handle file download from ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript app that sends ajax POST requests to a certain URL. Response might be a JSON string or it might be a file (as an attachment). I can easily detect Content-Type and Content-Disposition in my ajax call, but once I detect that the response contains a file, how do I offer the client to download it? I've read a number of similar threads here but none of them provide the answer I'm looking for.

Please, please, please do not post answers suggesting that I shouldn't use ajax for this or that I should redirect the browser, because none of this is an option. Using a plain HTML form is also not an option. What I do need is to show a download dialog to the client. Can this be done and how?

Comment: For those who read this article, read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request

Comment: I’ve removed your solution from the question. You are welcome to post it as an answer post below, but it doesn’t belong in the question post.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Create a form, use the POST method, submit the form - there's no need for an iframe.  When the server page responds to the request, write a response header for the mime type of the file, and it will present a download dialog - I've done this a number of times.

You want content-type of application/download - just search for how to provide a download for whatever language you're using.

Comment: As stated in the question:
"Using a plain HTML form is also not an option."

Comment: You can hide the form and fill it out programmatically - does that still not work?

Comment: No, because using a regular POST would navigate the browser to the POST URL. I don't want to navigate away from the page. I want to perform the request in the background, process the response and present it to the client.

Comment: If the server sends back headers like the other answer has, it opens in a new window - I've done it before.  It would only navigate away if your server-side script returned HTML code

Comment: Yes, but as stated in question: 
"Response might be a JSON string or it might be a file (as an attachment)."
I don't want to navigate away in either scenario.

Comment: @PavlePredic did you end up figuring out how to manage both response scenarios, i.e. JSON text response or download file response?

Comment: It works great in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE11.

Comment: Answer is not clear and the proposed solution doesn't work.

Comment: I can't see this `application/download` here https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: but in this way, how to handle the error message from the backend?

Answer (score 667):

Don't give up so quickly, because this can be done (in modern browsers) using parts of the FileAPI:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var blob = this.response;
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
            }

            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
    }
};
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send($.param(params, true));
```

Or if using jQuery.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: params,
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob' // to avoid binary data being mangled on charset conversion
    },
    success: function(blob, status, xhr) {
        // check for a filename
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
            }

            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code has been working for me for quite some time but recently stopped. Problem is the content-disposition is always null in Chrome, Edge, etc... Any reasons why and how to circumvent the problem? It is being returned according to the developer's toolbar in both browsers but when checking xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'), it's always null.

Comment: @Thierry Could be a CORS issue; check that Access-Control-Expose-Headers includes Content-Disposition (or is wildcard).

Comment: thanks for getting back. Took me too along to spot this but I had to introduce the withCredentials xhrFields and instead of adding it to the existing one, I created a separate entry causing the one for the 'blob' to be overwritten!! . Problem solved by merging both under the same xhrFields. Silly mistake on my end!! Thanks again.

Comment: @JonathanAmend how can I change download url? here it is `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` and is `https://sitename.com/randomName(no meaning name)` I create csv file in custom folder, how can I address the click action to there?

Comment: Note that this can get the filename wrong if: the filename has some `22` escaped quotes, or if instead of `filename=` the server returns a `filename*=`.

Comment: Trying the 'if using jQuery.ajax:' code, and it works perfectly for an attachment download. However if the response is JSON, the success function is not executed. A console.log in the first line of the success does not run on a Json response. Removing the xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' } fixes the Json but then the attachment fails. How to handle both?

Answer (score 51):

I faced the same issue and successfully solved it. My use-case is this.

"*Post JSON data to the server and receive an excel file.
That excel file is created by the server and returned as a response to the client. Download that response as a file with custom name in browser*"

```
$("#my-button").on("click", function(){

// Data to post
data = {
    ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
};

// Use XMLHttpRequest instead of Jquery $ajax
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var a;
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
        // Trick for making downloadable link
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
        // Give filename you wish to download
        a.download = "test-file.xls";
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }
};
// Post data to URL which handles post request
xhttp.open("POST", excelDownloadUrl);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
// You should set responseType as blob for binary responses
xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

The above snippet is just doing following

- Posting an array as JSON to the server using XMLHttpRequest.
- After fetching content as a blob(binary), we are creating a downloadable URL and attaching it to invisible "a" link then clicking it.

Here we need to carefully set few things at the server side. I set few headers in Python Django HttpResponse. You need to set them accordingly if you use other programming languages.

```
# In python django code
response = HttpResponse(file_content, content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Since I download xls(excel) here, I adjusted contentType to above one. You need to set it according to your file type. You can use this technique to download any kind of files.

Answer (score 35):

What server-side language are you using? In my app I can easily download a file from an AJAX call by setting the correct headers in PHP's response:

### Setting headers server-side

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

// The optional second 'replace' parameter indicates whether the header
// should replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of
// the same type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE
// as the second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type.
header("Cache-Control: private", false);

header("Content-type: " . $mimeType);

// $strFileName is, of course, the filename of the file being downloaded. 
// This won't have to be the same name as the actual file.
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$strFileName}\""); 

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($strFile));

// $strFile is a binary representation of the file that is being downloaded.
echo $strFile;
```

This will in fact 'redirect' the browser to this download page, but as @ahren alread said in his comment, it won't navigate away from the current page.

It's all about setting the correct headers so I'm sure you'll find a suitable solution for the server-side language you're using if it's not PHP.

### Handling the response client side

Assuming you already know how to make an AJAX call, on the client side you execute an AJAX request to the server. The server then generates a link from where this file can be downloaded, e.g. the 'forward' URL where you want to point to.
For example, the server responds with:

```
{
    status: 1, // ok
    // unique one-time download token, not required of course
    message: 'http://yourwebsite.com/getdownload/ska08912dsa'
}
```

When processing the response, you inject an `iframe` in your body and set the `iframe`'s SRC to the URL you just received like this (using jQuery for the ease of this example):

```
$("body").append("<iframe src='" + data.message +
  "' style='display: none;' ></iframe>");
```

If you've set the correct headers as shown above, the iframe will force a download dialog without navigating the browser away from the current page.

### Note

Extra addition in relation to your question; I think it's best to always return JSON when requesting stuff with AJAX technology. After you've received the JSON response, you can then decide client-side what to do with it. Maybe, for example, later on you want the user to click a download link to the URL instead of forcing the download directly, in your current setup you would have to update both client and server-side to do so.

Answer (score 33):

Here is how I got this working
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27563953/2845977

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '<URL_TO_FILE>',
  success: function(data) {
    var blob=new Blob([data]);
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="<FILENAME_TO_SAVE_WITH_EXTENSION>";
    link.click();
  }
});
```

### Updated answer using [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html)

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '<URL_TO_FILE>',
  success: download.bind(true, "<FILENAME_TO_SAVE_WITH_EXTENSION>", "<FILE_MIME_TYPE>")
});
```

Comment: Hi, do I need to have jQuery 3.0 > for this to work?

Comment: I'm also getting a blank pdf with both examples you gave. I am trying to get it to download a pdf file.

Comment: @gbade_ No, you dont need any specific jQuery version. Should work fine with all versions. Did you check if the PDF you are downloading has correct CORS headers? Any errors on console might help to debug

Comment: This worked for me using download.js: `success: function (response, status, request) { download(response, "filename.txt", "application/text"); }`

Answer (score 29):

For those looking for a solution from an Angular perspective, this worked for me:

```
$http.post(
  'url',
  {},
  {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}
).then(function (response) {
  var headers = response.headers();
  var blob = new Blob([response.data],{type:headers['content-type']});
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = "Filename";
  link.click();
});
```

Comment: This helped, but I need to preserve the original filename.  I see the filename in the response headers under "Content-Disposition", but I can't find that value in the response object in the code. Setting `link.download = ""` results in a random guid filename, and `link.download = null` results in a file named "null".

Comment: @Marie, you can record the file name at the time of upload by using the `INPUT` element's `HTMLInputElement.files` property. See [The MDN docs on the file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Getting_information_on_selected_files) for more detail.

Comment: Blob size is limited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307789/is-there-any-limitation-on-javascript-max-blob-size

Answer (score 21):

For those looking for a more modern approach, you can use the `fetch API`. The following code shows how to download a spreadsheet file.

```
fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(response => {
    const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
    const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = downloadUrl;
    a.download = "file.xlsx";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
})
```

I believe this approach to be much easier to understand than other `XMLHttpRequest` solutions. Also, it has a similar syntax to the `jQuery` approach, without the need to add any additional libraries.

Of course, I would advise checking to which browser you are developing, since this new approach won't work on IE. You can find the full browser compatibility list on the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#browser_compatibility).

**Important**: In this example I am sending a JSON request to a server listening on the given `url`. This `url` must be set, on my example I am assuming you know this part. Also, consider the headers needed for your request to work. Since I am sending a JSON, I must add the `Content-Type` header and set it to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, as to let the server know the type of request it will receive.

Comment: Awesome! To open this in a new tab instead of a download popup: use 
```
const window = open(downloadUrl, "_blank");
            if (window !== null)
                window.focus(); 
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this for multiple sets of data? Example, get back { fileOne: data, fileTwo: data, fileThree: data } from api call and generate three downloaded files at once? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't try that. But you can always compress the images in a zip file and download it. I will check if it is possible.

Answer (score 12):

I see you've already found out a solution, however I just wanted to add some information which may help someone trying to achieve the same thing with big POST requests.

I had the same issue a couple of weeks ago, indeed it isn't possible to achieve a "clean" download through AJAX, the Filament Group created a jQuery plugin which works exactly how you've already found out, it is called [jQuery File Download](https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-File-Download) however there is a downside to this technique.

If you're sending big requests through AJAX (say files +1MB) it will negatively impact responsiveness. In slow Internet connections you'll have to wait *a lot* until the request is sent and also wait for the file to download. It isn't like an instant "click" => "popup" => "download start". It's more like "click" => "wait until data is sent" => "wait for response" => "download start" which makes it appear the file double its size because you'll have to wait for the request to be sent through AJAX and get it back as a downloadable file.

If you're working with small file sizes <1MB you won't notice this. But as I discovered in my own app, for bigger file sizes it is almost unbearable.

My app allow users to export images dynamically generated, these images are sent through POST requests in base64 format to the server (it is the only possible way), then processed and sent back to users in form of .png, .jpg files, base64 strings for images +1MB are huge, this force users to wait more than necessary for the file to start downloading. In slow Internet connections it can be really annoying.

My solution for this was to temporary write the file to the server, once it is ready, dynamically generate a link to the file in form of a button which changes between "Please wait..." and "Download" states and at the same time, print the base64 image in a preview popup window so users can "right-click" and save it. This makes all the waiting time more bearable for users, and also speed things up.

**Update Sep 30, 2014:**

> Months have passed since I posted this, finally I've found a better approach to speed things up when working with big base64 strings. I now store base64 strings into the database (using longtext or longblog fields), then I pass its record ID through the jQuery File Download, finally on the download script file I query the database using this ID to pull the base64 string and pass it through the download function.

**Download Script Example:**

```
<?php
// Record ID
$downloadID = (int)$_POST['id'];
// Query Data (this example uses CodeIgniter)
$data       = $CI->MyQueries->GetDownload( $downloadID );
// base64 tags are replaced by [removed], so we strip them out
$base64     = base64_decode( preg_replace('#\[removed\]#', '', $data[0]->image) );
// This example is for base64 images
$imgsize    = getimagesize( $base64 );
// Set content headers
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my-file.png"');
header('Content-type: '.$imgsize['mime']);
// Force download
echo $base64;
?>
```

*I know this is way beyond what the OP asked, however I felt it would be good to update my answer with my findings. When I was searching for solutions to my problem, I read lots of **"Download from AJAX POST data"** threads which didn't give me the answer I was looking for, I hope this information helps someone looking to achieve something like this.*

Comment: The `jQuery File Download` only redirect me to the url. I call it like this: `jQuery.download("api/ide/download-this-file.php", {filePath: path2Down}, "POST");`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution using a temporary hidden form.

```
//Create an hidden form
var form = $('<form>', {'method': 'POST', 'action': this.href}).hide();

//Add params
var params = { ...your params... };
$.each(params, function (k, v) {
    form.append($('<input>', {'type': 'hidden', 'name': k, 'value': v}));
});

//Make it part of the document and submit
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();

//Clean up
form.remove();
```

Note that I massively use JQuery but you can do the same with native JS.

Answer (score 7):

I want to point out some difficulties that arise when using the technique in the accepted answer, i.e. using a form post:

1. You can't set headers on the request. If your authentication schema involves headers, a Json-Web-Token passed in the Authorization header, you'll have to find other way to send it, for example as a query parameter.
2. You can't really tell when the request has finished. Well, you can use a cookie that gets set on response, as done by [jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload), but it's FAR from perfect. It won't work for concurrent requests and it will break if a response never arrives.
3. If the server responds with a error, the user will be redirected to the error page.
4. You can only use the content types supported by a [form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). Which means you can't use JSON.

I ended up using the method of saving the file on S3 and sending a pre-signed URL to get the file.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you can create and submit a form to download via a POST request.  However, you don't have to do this manually.

One really simple library for doing exactly this is [jquery.redirect](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect).  It provides an API similar to the standard `jQuery.post` method:

```
$.redirect(url, [values, [method, [target]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a 3 years old question but I had the same problem today. I looked your edited solution but I think that it can sacrifice the performance because it has to make a double request. So if anyone needs another solution that doesn't imply to call the service twice then this is the way I did it:

```
<form id="export-csv-form" method="POST" action="/the/path/to/file">
    <input type="hidden" name="anyValueToPassTheServer" value="">
</form>
```

This form is just used to call the service and avoid to use a window.location(). After that you just simply have to make a form submit from jquery in order to call the service and get the file. It's pretty simple but this way you can make a download using a **POST**. I now that this could be easier if the service you're calling is a **GET**, but that's not my case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, gathered from different sources:
Server side implementation :

```
    String contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE;
    // Set headers
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename =" + fileName);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    // Copy file to output stream
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, servletOutputStream);
    } finally {
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        Utils.closeQuitely(servletOutputStream);
        fileToDownload = null;
    }
```

Client side implementation (using jquery):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',
    url: <download file url>,
    data: JSON.stringify(postObject),
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(message, textStatus, response) {
       var header = response.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
       var fileName = header.split("=")[1];
       var blob = new Blob([message]);
       var link = document.createElement('a');
       link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       link.download = fileName;
       link.click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). In my case with csv files, i did this (in coffescript):

```
  $.ajax
    url: "url-to-server"
    data: "data-to-send"
    success: (csvData)->
      blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' })
      saveAs(blob, "filename.csv")
```

I think for most complicated case, the data must be processed properly. Under the hood FileSaver.js implement the same approach of the answer of [Jonathan Amend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530630/jonathan-amend).

Comment: ..but can you download files usually in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

see: http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/
it'll return a blob as a response, which can then be put into filesaver

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution for downloading multiple files depending on some list which consists of some ids and looking up in database, files will be determined and ready for download - if those exist.
I am calling C# MVC action for each file using Ajax.

And Yes, like others said, it is possible to do it in jQuery Ajax.
I did it with Ajax success and I am always sending response 200.

So, this is the key:

```
  success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
```

And this is my code:

```
var i = 0;
var max = 0;
function DownloadMultipleFiles() {
            if ($(".dataTables_scrollBody>tr.selected").length > 0) {
                var list = [];
                showPreloader();
                $(".dataTables_scrollBody>tr.selected").each(function (e) {
                    var element = $(this);
                    var orderid = element.data("orderid");
                    var iscustom = element.data("iscustom");
                    var orderlineid = element.data("orderlineid");
                    var folderPath = "";
                    var fileName = "";

                    list.push({ orderId: orderid, isCustomOrderLine: iscustom, orderLineId: orderlineid, folderPath: folderPath, fileName: fileName });
                });
                i = 0;
                max = list.length;
                DownloadFile(list);
            }
        }
```

Then calling:

```
function DownloadFile(list) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OpenFile","OrderLines")',
            type: "post",
            data: list[i],
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());

            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                // check for a filename
                var filename = "";
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.append(a);
                    a.click();
                    a.remove();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
                else {
                    getErrorToastMessage("Production file for order line " + list[i].orderLineId + " does not exist");
                }
                i = i + 1;
                if (i < max) {
                    DownloadFile(list);
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            },
            complete: function () {
                if(i===max)
                hidePreloader();
            }
        });
    }
```

C# MVC:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult OpenFile(OrderLineSimpleModel model)
        {
            byte[] file = null;

            try
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    //code for getting file from api - part is missing here as not important for this example
                    file = apiHandler.Get<byte[]>(downloadApiUrl, token);

                    var contentDispositionHeader = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                    {
                        Inline = true,
                        FileName = fileName
                    };
                    //    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDispositionHeader.ToString() + "; attachment");
                    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(ex, "Error getting pdf", null);
                return Ok();
            }

            return File(file, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        }
```

As long as you return response 200, success in Ajax can work with it, you can check if file actually exist or not as the line below in this case would be false and you can inform user about that:

```
 if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

To get [Jonathan Amends](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530630/jonathan-amend) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/4472911) to work in Edge I made the following changes:

```
var blob = typeof File === 'function'
    ? new File([this.response], filename, { type: type })
    : new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
```

to this

```
var f = typeof File+"";
var blob = f === 'function' && Modernizr.fileapi
    ? new File([this.response], filename, { type: type })
    : new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
```

I would rather have posted this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution to download a web page in ajax. But I am referring to a page that must first be processed and then downloaded.

First you need to separate the page processing from the results download.

1) Only the page calculations are made in the ajax call.

```
$.post("CalculusPage.php", { calculusFunction: true, ID: 29, data1: "a", data2: "b" },

       function(data, status) 
       {
            if (status == "success") 
            {
                /* 2) In the answer the page that uses the previous calculations is downloaded. For example, this can be a page that prints the results of a table calculated in the ajax call. */
                window.location.href = DownloadPage.php+"?ID="+29;
            }               
       }
);

// For example: in the CalculusPage.php

    if ( !empty($_POST["calculusFunction"]) ) 
    {
        $ID = $_POST["ID"];

        $query = "INSERT INTO ExamplePage (data1, data2) VALUES ('".$_POST["data1"]."', '".$_POST["data2"]."') WHERE id = ".$ID;
        ...
    }

// For example: in the DownloadPage.php

    $ID = $_GET["ID"];

    $sede = "SELECT * FROM ExamplePage WHERE id = ".$ID;
    ...

    $filename="Export_Data.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$filename");

    ...
```

I hope this solution can be useful for many, as it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

If response is an **Array Buffer**, try this under onsuccess event in Ajax:

```
 if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
          var binary = '';
          var bytes = new Uint8Array(event.data);
          for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
              binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
          }
          $("#some_id").append("<li><img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + window.btoa(binary) + "\"/></span></li>");
          return;
      }
```

- where event.data is response received in success function of xhr event.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar solution to @alain-cruz's one, but in nuxt/vue with multiple downloads. I know browsers block multiple file downloads, and I also have API which returns a set of csv formatted data.I was going to use JSZip at first but I needed IE support so here is my solution. If anyone can help me improve this that would be great, but it's working for me so far.

API returns:

```
data : {
  body: {
    fileOne: ""col1", "col2", "datarow1.1", "datarow1.2"...so on",
    fileTwo: ""col1", "col2"..."
  }
}
```

page.vue:

```
<template>
  <b-link @click.prevent="handleFileExport">Export<b-link>
</template>

export default = {
   data() {
     return {
       fileNames: ['fileOne', 'fileTwo'],
     }
   },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
       fileOne: (state) => state.exportFile.fileOne,
       fileTwo: (state) => state.exportFile.fileTwo,
    }),
  },
  method: {
    handleExport() {
      //exportFileAction in store/exportFile needs to return promise
      this.$store.dispatch('exportFile/exportFileAction', paramsToSend)
        .then(async (response) => {
           const downloadPrep = this.fileNames.map(async (fileName) => {
           // using lodash to get computed data by the file name
           const currentData = await _.get(this, `${fileName}`);
           const currentFileName = fileName;
           return { currentData, currentFileName };
         });
         const response = await Promise.all(downloadPrep);
         return response;
       })
       .then(async (data) => {
         data.forEach(({ currentData, currentFileName }) => {
           this.forceFileDownload(currentData, currentFileName);
         });
       })
       .catch(console.error);
    },
    forceFileDownload(data, fileName) {
     const url = window.URL
         .createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }));
     const link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = url;
     link.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}.csv`);
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Naren Yellavula's solution and got it working with few changes to the script, after trying several other solutions using jquery. But, jquery will not download a zip file properly. I can't unzip the file after download.
In my use case, I have to upload a zip file, which is unzipped in the Servlet, files are processed and zipped again before the zip file is downloaded to the client. This is what you need to do on client side.

```js
$('#fileUpBtn').click(function (e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var file = $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0];
         var formdata = new FormData();
         formdata.append('file', file);

        // Use XMLHttpRequest instead of Jquery $ajax to download zip files
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
                a.download = "modified_" + file.name;
                a.style.display = 'none';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "<URL to Servlet>", true);
        xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
        xhttp.send(formdata);     
     });

 <div class="form-group">
     <label id="fileUpLabel" for="fileUpload"></label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" id="fileUpload" name="file" accept="" required/>
 </div>
 <button class="btn" type="submit" id="fileUpBtn"></button>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.

Comment: Explanation:  
1. Onclick function for upload button  
2. Prevent default form submission on button click  
3. Select first attached file  
4. Formdata with name, value pairs sent to Servlet  
5. Uploaded file set in Formdata  
6. onreadystatechange: handler for asynchronous response from Servlet  
7. final success response from Servlet  
8. a is link to which data from Servlet is set as an object  
9. file name to save the object as  
10. simulate link click to save file  
11. response data is removed  
12. open connection to Servlet  
13. set response type  
14. send to Servlet

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me.

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
$(".download-button").click(function(){
var val1 = $(this).data("column1");
var val2 = $(this).data("column2");
        var val3 = $("#SearchString").val();
var val4 = $(this).closest("tr").find(".textbox").val();

$.ajax({
            url: '/TestDownload/DownloadFile',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                val1 : val1,
                val2: val2,
                val3 : val3,
                val4: val4

            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                var contentDisposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-disposition');
                var fileName = '';
                if (contentDisposition && contentDisposition.indexOf('attachment') != -1) {
                    var startIndex = contentDisposition.indexOf('filename=') + 9;
                    var endIndex = contentDisposition.indexOf(';', startIndex);
                    if (endIndex === -1) {
                        endIndex = contentDisposition.length;
                    }
                    fileName = contentDisposition.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                }

                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                $("#errorMessage").text("File downloaded successfully.");


            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){                    
                $("#errorMessage").text(xhr.responseText);
            }
            });
            });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).